# Как реализовать в поле ввода - подсказка

Tags: jquery, css, javascript

Как реализовать в поле ввода - подсказка* (реализовать одним цветом легко)

Подскажите варианты как реализовать разными color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартом цветные placeholder-ы не предусмотрены. Реализовать их можно следующим образом: делаем `div` с подсказкой, раскрашенной так, как нам нужно; задаём ему `z-index: 100`; позиционируем его поверх `input`-а; JavaScript-ом заставляем `div` появляться и исчезать по событиям `focus` и `blur` `input`-а. Получится как-то так: http://jsfiddle.net/aYveM/

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант **:input-placeholder**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    #999;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    color:    #999;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color:    #999;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    color:    #999;
}
```

Стащил [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css) :)
Ну а дальше [как угодно их](http://jsfiddle.net/weKxX/) :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но вопрос не об этом - я это и сам реализовал + в Опере не работает стилизация пласехолдера. Если получиться вот так 
http://jsfiddle.net/aYveM/ этим методом - тогда отлично будет.

Comment: А вот, теперь понял вопрос :)
Да, тут так просто не получится :(